# Expo React Native App: How to install a specific version of modules in dependencys?

Tags: react-native, npm, export-to-csv

In my app I need to have a specific version of @expo/config-plugins (6.0.0). I have installed it via

```
npm i @expo/config-plugins@6.0.0
```

but now 2 of my modules are using a wrong and different versions so Im getting this:

```
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~6.0.0
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
  @expo/config-plugins@7.2.5
```

How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21423) solution while trying to downgrade from SDK 49.

Add resolutions to `package.json` like this:

```json
 "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.2",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.0.2"
  }
```

Delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`.
After this `npx expo-doctor` should pass.